# Why can't I see the options of a drop-down menu in the source code?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to select an option in a drop-down menu using selenium's `Select`, but I can't get anything out of it. My code at the moment is like this

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cmbTBC"))
select.select_by_value("172")
```

which presents me with the error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: 172`.

If I inspect the element I can see a list of options, including one with value '172', but going to the source code shows no options at all. Here's the part with the drop-down menu at the source.

```
<select Id="cmbTBC" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TBC must be a number." data-val-required="The TBC field is required." id="IdTBC" name="IdTBC" onchange="CreateBC.DescriptionTBC(this.value)">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is only one option in this html, and it doesn't have `value="172"`.

Comment: That's my point. If I use Chrome's Inspect I can see about 142 options, but in the source code there's only this.

Comment: What do you mean by source code?

Comment: Using the "view page source"(or ctrl u). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: What steps should the user actually take in manual mode to see the entire list of options? As far as I can suppose the options are loaded on some circumstances.

Comment: Manually the user clicks on the box and then it shows the list of options. I've managed to select an option by using `send_keys`, but I don't know why it works like this.

Answer (score 0):

The options are probably loaded by JavaScript, you can wait for them to appear with custom ExpectedCondition

```
def wait_for_options(self, select):
    if select.options:
        return True
    return False

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cmbTBC"))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda x: self.wait_for_options(select))
select.select_by_value("172")
```

You should also notice there are to `id` attributes, one of them is with uppercase `I`, `Id="cmbTBC"` and `id="IdTBC"`. You need the lowercase one, there might be another dropdown without options with `id="cmbTBC"`, and this is what the driver locate

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("IdTBC"))
```

Comment: I've tried it before, but it didn't work. I managed to get a result not using `send_keys`, but I'm not sure why it works. Also I can't get the option I want, since it gives me the first one with "2", but I want the option that begins with "29".

Comment: @Luck Maybe you need to click the dropdown to make it load the options. Try `element = driver.find_element_by_id("IdTBC") element.click()` select = Select(element)` and then wait for the options to appear.

Comment: I've tried it before, and although it doesn't give me an error it also doesn't give me anything. It doesn't even click on the menu.